# is there a way to make the GUI stay ontop of fullscreen games?

Tags: pysimplegui

The title question, simple, is there a way to keep my GUI on top of full screen games?

I managed to do it while the games are borderless but I feel that could be done more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use option `keep_on_top=True` in `sg.Window`, and method `window.maximize()` to maixmize window.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlue')
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 32))
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Bordless, maxmize and keep-on-top window')]
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, keep_on_top=True,finalize=True)
window.maximize()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

Comment: I was doing everything you did,but the maximize command,witch is useless since you can't use the screens behind it....

Comment: "you can't use the screens behind it.", what it mean for ?

Comment: for a game,I need to use the window while in game,but my on top function won't go on top of the game ,unless I make it borderless

Comment: What game what window ? still not sure what you mean, so I have to let it be.